# How to use fitted_model.forecast() for AutoML forecasting model?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Say I have a dataset with a monthly granularity with the following columns:

- Timestamp
- Issues (i.e. number of GitHub issues)

There is data for each month for all of 2016-2019, so I divide the data accordingly.

- `training_data`: 2016-2017
- `validation_data`: 2018
- `holdout_data`: 2019

If I have a `fitted_model` that is a `ForecastingPipelineWrapper` which is the best run from AutoML where I passed gave it `training_data` and `validation_data`.

Looking at the [ForecastingPipelineWrapper class docstring](https://gist.github.com/swanderz/c68514d955bebf20f48ffd91aabdc55d) documentation only serves to confuse me more. What is `X_past`, `X_future`, and `Y_future`?

How do I use the above dataframes with `fitted_model.forecast()` to manually validate model fit on the `holdout_data` dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following notebook illustrates how to leverage y_past, x_past, y_future, x_future, and fitted_model.forecast in the bottom half, 'Forecasting away from training data'. https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/automated-machine-learning/forecasting-high-frequency/auto-ml-forecasting-function.ipynb

The notebook will be a much better guide to grasping these concepts than perhaps a docstring doc. Should you have any more questions or need clarity, let us know!